# How do Death Eaters fight against Dementors?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters, dementors, patronus-charm

It's quite popularly stated that Snape was the only Death Eater capable of creating a Patronus (due to his love for Lily). Also, a Patronus is the only weapon against Dementors.

How do Death Eaters (except Snape of course) fight against Dementors? Do they just die after encountering Dementors as there's no other option?

Or, do Dementors just not attack Death Eaters because there's nothing to feed on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There are ways to fight Dementors other than a Patronus.

When Harry has to write an essay for Snape, he’s fairly sure he’ll get a bad grade since he doesn’t agree with him on how best to fight Dementors - proving that there have to be other ways. If the Patronus Charm was the only way to fight Dementors, there’d be no possibility of disagreement.

> “Harry fully expected to receive low marks on his, because he had disagreed with Snape on the best way to tackle Dementors, but he did not care: Slughorn’s memory was the most important thing to him now.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 21 (The Unknowable Room)*</sup></sub>

So, there are other ways to fight Dementors than the Patronus Charm, so Death Eaters could use another method. It’s simply not true that a Death Eater would never need to fight off Dementors. They’re only the Death Eaters’ “natural allies” because the Death Eaters provide them with more victims when they’re in power. However, Death Eaters are not immune to Dementors, and Dementors don’t care much about the moral alignment of their dinner.

Comment: But is it ever specified anywhere what those other methods are?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Unfortunately, no. We know there *are* other methods but we don’t know *what* the other methods are.  (My personal theory - though not confirmed - is that blocking your emotions with Occlumency might work. If they can’t find emotions they might not be able to feed on them.)

Answer (score 16):

Death Eaters have no need of Patronus charms.

From [this interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) with JK Rowling:

> Samantha: Was snape the only death eater who could produce a full patronus
>
> J.K. Rowling: Yes, because a Patronus is used against things that the Death Eaters generally generate, or fight alongside. They would not need Patronuses.

Quote to support the above assertion, from Lord V talking to his recently recalled Death Eaters in Goblet of Fire:

> Voldemort moved on, and stopped, staring at the space - large enough for two people - that separated Malfoy and the next man.
>
> 'The Lestranges should stand here,' said Voldemort quietly. 'But they are entombed in Azkaban. They were faithful. They went to Azkaban rather than renounce me…When Azkaban is broken open, the Lestranges will be honored beyond their dreams. **The dementors will join us…they are our natural allies…** we will recall the banished giants…I shall have all my devoted servants returned to me, and an army of creatures whom all fear…'

Comment: I don't think Dementors are generated by Death Eaters..

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how they might fight a dementor, though.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - No, but the dementors fight alongside the Death Eaters. They don't need to defend against allies.

Comment: Who said that... Dementors were guarding Azkaban where many Death Eaters were held.

Comment: Ministry of Magic controls Dementors. And, Dementors  were kept free after first wizarding war. Means, Death Eaters and Dementors weren't allies.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Yes, that's why the Death Eaters were unable to stage a mass breakout, because MoM controlled the dementors. If you want to argue against a direct JK quote, I can't help you much.

Comment: Wow, Dementors are natural Allies? Thanks for adding the quote from GoF.

Comment: The Dementors like most magical creatures simply ally themselves with whoever gives them a better deal considering Voldemort wanted a Pureblood revolution eventually ending in Muggle Genocide he pretty much wins all magical creature votes unless they have morals.

Answer (score 4):

The Patronus Charm isn't *the only way* to to fight off the dementors as Harry argues with Professor Snape on the *best way* to tackle the Dementors in his sixth year.

I don't have the exact quotation at hand, however you may see this [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dementor) under the heading of protection.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have citations?

Comment: I would be helpful if you posted the relevant contents of your link